# how to use xgboost in visual studio C++ environment under windows platform?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, machine-learning, xgboost

I have build xgboost in VS, But I don't know how to use xgboost in my c++ program(windows visual studio), but the official tutorials lacks of document about that.
I don't need python, R, Java wrappers solutions. 
thanks.

Comment: I finally figured out how to use xgboost in VS C++ environment and writed it in my blog:http://qsalg.com/?p=388( However it's Chinese), I hope this could help anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download their SDK & Install
This will give their lib and includes
2) In your C++ editor, specify the Lib and include file location

With these steps, you can link your application with their libraries

Comment: Of course I did it. But I need some tutorials that how to use xgboost in c++.